# togglegroup.getSelectedToogle() always returns null JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, toggle

I have this code to get the values from the selected `ToggleGroup`.

When I run this code however, I get an empty list back. I can't seem to figure out how to solve this.

```
   public TestPane(TestService service) {
        this.service = service;

        this.setPrefHeight(300);
        this.setPrefWidth(750);

        this.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        this.setVgap(5);
        this.setHgap(5);

        questionField = new Label();
        vragen = service.getAllQuestions();
        Question question = vragen.iterator().next();
        questionField.setText(question.getQuestion());
        vragen.remove(question);

        add(questionField, 0, 0, 1, 1);

        statementGroup = new ToggleGroup();
        Set<String> statements = question.getStatements();
        System.out.println(statements);
        int i = 1;
        for (String st : statements) {
            radio = new RadioButton(st);
            radio.setText(st);
            radio.setUserData(st);
            radio.setToggleGroup((ToggleGroup) statementGroup.getUserData());
            add(radio, 0, i++);
        }

        submitButton = new Button("Submit");
        add(submitButton, 0, i);
        submitButton.setOnAction(new SubmitHandler(this,service));
    }

    public List<String> getSelectedStatements() {
        List<String> selected = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (statementGroup.getSelectedToggle() != null) {
            selected.add(statementGroup.getSelectedToggle().getUserData().toString());
        }
        return selected;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line is incorrect:

```
radio.setToggleGroup((ToggleGroup) statementGroup.getUserData());
```

The correct call would be:

```
radio.setToggleGroup(statementGroup);
```

To answer the question "why": The `getSelectedToggle` method of the `ToggleGroup` returns null all the time, because there are no toggles associated with it, as

```
(ToggleGroup) statementGroup.getUserData()
```

returns `null`, therefore actually `radio.setToggleGroup(null)` will be executed, which means: the `RadioButton` has no toggle group.